# Expected value of Stock Price, Poisson Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I would appreciate a hint regarding the following question (taken from Durret, Essentials of Stochastic Processes, questions 2.38

"Let $S_t$ be the price of stock at time t and suppose that at times of a Poisson
process with rate  the price is multiplied by a random variable $X_i$ > 0 with mean
$\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. That is,

$S_t = S_0\prod_{i=1}^{N(t)}X_i$

where the product is 1 if $N(t) = 0$. Find ES(t)/ and varS(t).

Is this an example of thinning?

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with thinning. You need to take conditional expectation with respect to N(t) to get the mean and conditional variance formula to get the variance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You start by the conditional expectation with respect to $N_t$.

$E[S_t|N_t] = S_0\prod_{i=1}^{N(t)} EX_i$ 
 with the additional hypothesis that the process $N$ and the $X_i$s are independent, so

$$E[S_t|N_t] = S_0 \mu^{N(t)}
$$

Let $r$ be the rate of the Poisson process, we have
$$E[S_t] = EE[S_t|N_t] 
= S_0 \exp(-rt)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mu^{k}\frac{(rt)^k}{k!}
= S_0 \exp(rt(\mu-1))$$

We also have via the same computation:
$$E[S_t^2] = E[S_0^2 (\sigma^2 + \mu^2)^N_t]
= S_0^2 \exp(rt(\sigma^2 + \mu^2 - 1))$$

so $Var[S_t] = S_0^2 (\exp(rt(\sigma^2 + \mu^2 - 1)) - \exp(2rt(\mu-1)))$

One can actually compute the characteristic function of such a process (in terms of the characteristic function of the $X_i$s), this is a simple case of the Lévy–Khintchin representation.

Comment: Hello, I downvoted your answer. This is not because I think it is a bad answer, but on this site, it is the norm that people do not give answers to questions which shows no attempt. This, imo, can easily be a homework question and the OP showed no attempt at it. This is why I left a comment below the question on something to look at, but I did not post answer myself. I hope you can understand.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Also @Lost1, thanks for the hint, that is all I wanted not a full answer that is why I asked for a "hint".

Comment: I wanted to ask actually: what do you mean by Levy Khintchin representation in this case. If we take the log of $S_t$, it is a Compound Poisson process with jump distribution $X_i$, so we know what $S_t$ is by Levy Khintchin formula (by setting the argument of the Levy Khintchin formula a complex number). Is this what you meant? I do not know what Levy Khitchin representation is. Would be nice if you can elaborate.

Comment: The Levy Khintchin representation is a formula that express the Fourier transformation of a Levy process, that is, a (continous in Probability) process with independant stationnary increments. The formula is especially simple for a Compound Poisson process, and you can find it with the same computation as I did, just put the exp function in the conditional expectation: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution#Properties)

Comment: And if you want to know more about Levy processes: [link](http://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/66/50/21/PDF/warsaw_handout.pdf)

Comment: yeah, that is what i thought you meant.

Comment: @Lost1 shouldn't you actually downvote the question, then? The answer is useful to others who will eventually reach this page when searching for help in similar problems.

Comment: @AndréTerra that goes without saying...

Comment: Why do you have that $E[S_{t}^{2}] = E[S_{0}^{2}(\sigma^{2} + \mu^{2})^{N(t)}$ and not $E[S_{t}^{2}] = E[(S_{0}\mu^{N(t)})^{2}] = E[(S_{0}^{2}\mu^{2N(t)})]$?